# Express a number in a special format in Android

Tags: android, xml, textview, special-characters

I have a question, I am doing an App that is a kind of bill however I don't know how to express in a textview for example:

1120 as $1.120 or something like this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[numberformat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html) is your solution :
    Test code :

```
int = 1236;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
Log.i("test", nf.format(nb));
```

show output :

```
1,236
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of solutions to format numbers in Android which of course depend on the nature of your app and your requirements.

Because you are using a money value in your example, I would look into [Big Decimal](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html) at has numerous precision and rounding methods.

Here's a little example for you, note that it is not localised!

```
BigDecimal theAmount = new BigDecimal(int);

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00");
// ^ This is set manually, you could use a localised format to have Android set the 
// values based on locale like this: DecimalFormat.getInstance();

decimalFormat.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
decimalFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(3);
decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
// ^ There are a lot of methods to check out here!

TextView yourTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(theAmount.divide(new BigDecimal(1000))));
```

Good luck!